# Can't activate WPML Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I have installed WPML plugin but it doesn't let me activate.

I get this error

Sorry, you have to activate the plugin wpml!

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );


// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Comment: What code should i change to active it

Comment: as you have purchased this plugin you will get a better solution from WPML support. as they will check your website to check what's causing this problem.

Comment: I would say that you are trying to activate one of many WPML extension plugins that depend on WPML CMS. activate WPML CMS then activate the rest